# Java-8 Lambda expression - handle Exception

Tags: lambda, java-8

I have this lambda expression where this expression

```
institutionUserConnectionService.getActiveInstitutionUserConnectionsByUser(u)
```

throws a `BusinessWxception`. Is there any possibility to handle this exception?

```
users.parallelStream()
    .forEach(u -> institutionUserConnections
        .addAll(institutionUserConnectionService
             .getActiveInstitutionUserConnectionsByUser(u)));
```

Comment: Can you format your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure:

```
users.parallelStream()
     .forEach(u -> {
         try {
             institutionUserConnections.addAll(
                 institutionUserConnectionService.getActiveInstitutionUserConnectionsByUser(u)));
         }
         catch (BusinessWxception e) {
             // decide what to do here
         }
    });
```